# Getting Android app root folder

Tags: android, path, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm facing an issue trying to get the app root folder, the problem comes in an emulator with Marshmallow. When I do `context.getFilesDir()` it returns a wrong path:

> data/user/0/com.android.appname/files/

When it should be:

> data/data/com.android.appname/files/

Somebody know why is this happening and how to solve it or another way to get the right path to the app root folder?

Comment: "it returns a wrong path" -- that seems perfectly fine, particularly for newer versions of Android. What makes you think that it is wrong?

Comment: Because the folder where my app has stored the files is the second one.

Comment: And how precisely are you determining this? Bear in mind that the filesystem will look different when viewed through tools like `adb shell`.

Comment: Yes I know, I checked it through adb and DDMS, the first path is empty, neither the `files` and `package` folder. The second one has the app files

Comment: And when you checked it **through your app**, are your files available at `/data/user/0/com.android.appname/files/`?

Comment: That path is empty (checking with adb). I can reach until the `0` folder, nothing below

Comment: Use `context.getExternalFilesDir(null);` For me that returns `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/package.name/files`

Comment: Thank you @Hobojoe but I need the app root folder, not the SDCard folder

Answer (score 2):

`/data/user/0/com.android.appname/files/` is a perfectly valid path to be returned by `getFilesDir()`. That directory will be usable by your app.

`adb` is not your app. Its view of the filesystem will be different.

The exact location of where `getFilesDir()` maps to on the actual filesystem — or where tools like `adb` will see it — will vary based on several criteria, including OS version, which user account is running your app (remember: Android supports multiple users!), and possibly device manufacturer/custom ROM changes.

Comment: What I want is to copy the SQLite database of my app from the root folder to the SDCard. The `database` folder is in the second path, in the first one the app can't find it. It makes sense what you say but neither the app can find the database in that path. Can you tell me why the app creates the database in the `/data/data...` folder if it the other one is the "correct"?

Comment: @AlbertoMéndez: They are both correct, because they both map to the same place.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that, but it seems it doesn't do it, because it falls in the catch (`IOException`) trying to get the database file and throws the message, `File not found`. That's the reason I came here to ask

Comment: @AlbertoMéndez: I recommend that you open a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem

Comment: You are right @CommonsWare `data/user/0/...` is a symlink to the data folder, it seems I did a mistake when trying to reach the databases folder. Thank you